# Rails ActiveStorage Using Custom S3 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I want to use Rails ActiveStorage, but I am using non-AWS S3 API object storage.

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: ""
  secret_access_key: ""
  region: ""
  bucket: ""
```

On the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#amazon-s3-service), it says that we need the region, my S3 API has no region. Is the any way to use custom S3 API?

Comment: I'm not using AWS S3 @fool-dev It only have the ip

Comment: Sorry my comment was removed for miss clicking

Comment: I'm not using AWS S3. I don't understand this, without `AWS S3` how you use Amazon storage, look https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby#configuration. they have says You will need to configure credentials and a `region`, either in configuration files or environment variables

Comment: S3 is already a public protocol. There are a lot of other services that implement storage service with S3 protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using the `endpoint` key on the configuration file. It look like this.

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: "123"
  secret_access_key: "asd"
  endpoint: "http://192.168.1.201:30103"
  bucket: "test"
```

Do not need to use any region since there is not any. I found it at the bottom of the S3 Ruby gem AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html